# Python Requests: assert status_code is not failing

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to fail a test with a specific error message if an api call returns a 403 code. I've tried a couple options:

```
if int(addresses.status_code) is 403:
    fail("Auth Error: Missing Role {}".format(response.json()))

assert addresses.status_code is not 403

assert addresses.status_code is not codes.forbidden

assert addresses.status_code is codes.ok
```

The only one of these that is failing is the last, `assert addresses.status_code is codes.ok`. However, the status code the api call is responding with *is* 403.  I've played around with making sure the types are the same, etc, but not sure where else to go.

How do I test that the status_code is not a specific value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`is` tests for *identity*. The status code is indeed not the same object as `403` or `codes.forbidden`. The status value is an integer, not a singleton enumeration object.

Use `==` to test if the *value* is the same:

```
if addresses.status_code == 403:
    # ...

assert addresses.status_code != 403
assert addresses.status_code != codes.forbidden
assert addresses.status_code == codes.ok
```

or just use

```
addresses.raise_for_status()  # raises an exception if not 1xx, 2xx or 3xx
```

The [`Response.raise_for_status()` method](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.raise_for_status) raises a `requests.exceptions.HTTPError` exception (a subclass of `requests.exceptions.RequestException`, in turn a `OSError` subclass).

Note that *sometimes* `is` will work with integers, or any number of other types. But unless there is specific documentation that you can use identity tests, you have instead found an implementation detail where Python will have re-used objects for performance reasons. Such is the case for small integers (from -5 through to 256), and for strings in certain cases, and many other corner cases. So `address.status_code is 200` just happens to work in current CPython interpreters, but this is *not a given and should not be relied upon*.

Comment: Worse, the status code _could_ be the same object as `403`, so you can't really rely on `is` being _either_ true or false here. Of course (default-configured) CPython 3.6 only "interns" integers across compilation units up to about half this size, so it will always say false, but that's just an implementation detail of (default-configured) CPython 3.6, not something you want to rely on in code.

Comment: @abarnert: yes, and 200 is such an interned number, so `address.status_code is 200` magically works.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `is`, which checks the identity of two objects. For comparing `int`s you should use `==`. In fact, always use `==` except when checking singletons (i.e. `None`) or when you actually need to.